# Running scheduled job from Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I'm looking to use Cassandra to store data which will be picked by some scheduling framework and will process those asynchronously at some time in future. Does anyone know if there are any scheduling frameworks that can be hooked up with Cassandra to make sure multiple instances of scheduling framework can work on the data set in parallel. Challenge here will be when a particular row is picked by any instance of scheduler framework, it should not be picked by any other instance. In RDMS I know we can achieve that by row locking mechanism but not sure if there is a cleaner way to achieve that in Cassandra. Please let me know if there is any framework of that nature to pick up those tasks.